# Can figure out JSON mismatch

Tags: android, arrays, json

I m trying to get the string from "photo_reference" from the JSON given below.However, I am getting an exception of mismatch.But I think I have done right.Mismatch exception is on result, But it can be clearly seen that results is array of objects

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {


         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",

         "photos" : [
            {
               ,
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
               "width" : 519
            }
         ],

      },
     ,
      {

         "name" : "Bucks Party Cruise",

         "photos" : [
            {

               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAA48AX5MsHIMiuipON_Lgh97hPiYDFkxx_vnaZQMOcvcQwYN92o33t5RwjRpOue5R47AjfMltntoz71hto40zqo7vFyxhDuuqhAChKGRQ5mdO5jv5CKWlzi182PICiOb37PiBtiFt7lSLe1SedoyrD-xIQD8xqSOaejWejYHCN4Ye2XBoUT3q2IXJQpMkmffJiBNftv8QSwF4",
               "width" : 800
            }
         ],

      },
```

Here is my code to get photo_reference

```
 var arr: JSONArray = JSONArray(result)
                    var jsonObject:JSONObject=arr.getJSONObject(0)
                    var array:JSONArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos")
                    var obj:JSONObject=array.getJSONObject(0)
                    var photoref:String=obj.getString("photo_reference")
```

Comment: Validate your json data. Line 8 -- "photos" : [{, -- error. Check the ',' comma added inside json object. Validate & check. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMaxF.png

Comment: You may test yourself the json errors at   https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

you need convert your root object as JSONObject

```
  var rootObject :JSONObject = JSONObject(result);
  var arr: JSONArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("results")
  var jsonObject:JSONObject=arr.getJSONObject(0)
  var array:JSONArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("photos")
  var obj:JSONObject=array.getJSONObject(0)
  var photoref:String=obj.getString("photo_reference")
```